# Copyright notice year date after small revision?

Tags: european-union, sweden, copyright-notice

We produce a Swedish boardgame in Sweden for the Swedish market, which includes a 4 page leaflet describing the game rules. This was originally published in 2008. We are now producing a new batch, and are making a few very small adjustments in the rules (most essentially adding a note about our Facebook page).

What year should the new revision's copyright notice specify?
2008?
2019?
2008, 2019?
2008-2019?
Anything else?

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our [tour page](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @isakbob Thanks, I'm an experienced Stack Exchange user, so I pretty much knew all of it. I also already know that at least in Sweden a copyright notice has no legal significance, and that this site is not to be regarded as proper legal advice. Still, I'd like to know how the year in a copyright notice is supposed to be treated for works that are revised, as in the described case. (I'd actually also like to know what would be the right way to handle it in e.g. websites and software, where content is revised in a more continuous manner).

Comment: Related: [Which year to put in copyright notice when mixing old content?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/18123/which-year-to-put-in-copyright-notice-when-mixing-old-content). You should also look at notices published in your country to see what is the common convention used.

Comment: @Brandin Yes, I saw that one, but I can't see that it fully addresses the case when a text is revised, as opposed to composed of parts from different dates of origin.

Comment: @KjellRilbe Based on that answer, the notice standard for the US is to put (at least) the year of the *first* publication. The year of the additional revisions is sometimes notated after a hyphen or dash, e.g. a notice like "1987-1997" means it was first published in 1987 and revised one or more times since then, the most recent time being in 1997 according to that notice. Whether the revisions added new material or modified existing material is usually not part of the notice, unless if you want to copyright modifications separately for some reason (e.g. source code with several authors).

Comment: @Brandin That sounds like an answer.

Comment: @Brandin Good, thanks! Feel free to write that as an answer instead, and I'll mark it as such.